5th year PhD student with no publications. How to proceed?
I am doing a PhD in physics at a US school in my 5th and I would like to seek some advice. My PI provides absolutely zero guidance and it is not possible to have any technical discussion with him. Guidance is "at least on paper" provided by the postdocs. I have no publication up to now and I feel like I don't have an actual working research project. During the last two years, I have asked other professors if I can switch to their group, but they refused. I do not really want to drop out. Is there a hope in my situation or is it very likely that there is no hope in submitting a dissertation? What should I do in this situation? Is it possible to finish a research project with no supervision from a PI?

What field is this? In some it is no problem.

theoretical physics

Is changing to a different institution an option?

I hope this is the case, but I am not really sure how to get the recommendations and how professors at another institution will think about my case, given that I have spent around 3 years now working on research after the 2 years of courses but with no publication output.

"Is it possible to finish a research project with no supervision from a PI?" Yes (depending on how independent a student you are), but you need to have an actual viable research project and get repeated feedback on it from experts. It seems like you have neither at this moment.

It seems that you have done well in your graduate classes, so you can ask professors from those classes if they would be willing to write you letters. The trouble is, you are facing a very short deadline if you were to apply this year (maybe you already missed deadlines in many graduate schools).

Take a look at my answer here. This is not quite your situation though, but, I think, my answer still applies.

In my department, if the advisor is cool with that, then the student is fine. I hate to say this, but in some departments, it is really like this. Even if people may despise this

You ask whether there is hope of graduating, but the focus of your question is on missing publications. What is the relationship? Is it necessary to have publications to graduate?

@WolfgangBangerth I don't think it would be possible to graduate without publications.

@quark You should know what your graduation requirements are by your fifth year.

To me, the most important issue in your post is that you don't have a research project and the advisor seems unwilling or unable to get you to a viable one. In a highly theoretical field (mine was math) the lack of publication may be less important, but I'm guessing there for theoretical physics.
If you have passed comprehensive exams you are in a fairly good place intellectually, though without a viable project perhaps in trouble for finishing.
I had an unhelpful advisor after four years and changed institutions to succeed. It was to a higher ranked institution, actually, and a wonderful advisor, full of ideas. The change in institutions was facilitated by another professor who was able to attest to my likely success, but it wasn't my advisor.
The quickest path might be to find another group at the same university, but it that is impossible, as you suggest, moving might be necessary. Look to other trusted faculty for help and advice in that, as in other possible options.
Some people can succeed without guidance, but I think they are rare. I was not. I don't think I was really a mathematician until after I'd earned the doctorate. I had some skills, but hadn't yet achieved the capability for self guidance and problem/project insight and evaluation. If you are like that, then you may need to take drastic action. The lack of a project after five years is an indicator.
In highly theoretical fields, the highest level is insight about "what might be true" and how to go about obtaining evidence (proof in math) about the correctness of the insight. A good advisor should have that.

Thanks, I have passed my qualifiers and also all first-year PhD courses with top grades. I have a few ideas that I am trying to work on, but I find it hard to write a manuscript from scratch without any external guidance or collaboration. And honestly I find it depressing to find almost all of my classmates proceeding much more quickly than me, so I feel like I am handicapped.

@quark, the question is if the problems of writing a manuscript are based on describing the methodology and summarising outputs or if they are more technical. In the case of technical issues, you usually copy the style from the papers of others, or you may ask librarians of your university to help you. If the problem is summarizing your thoughts, what about reaching fellow scientists elsewhere and asking them for help?

You are in a very bad situation and you are running up against the deadlines that most programs have. You should talk as soon as possible with the people that supervise the Ph.D. program, in this order: the director of graduate studies in the department if this position exists, the chairman of the department, and the dean (which depending on the institution can be the dean of graduate studies, the dean of Sciences, the dean of Arts and Sciences). You approach them in this order.
It is disconcerting that you were not able to be accepted in a different group. This either means that you have acquired a reputation of being a student who is not creative, or more likely, it can mean that nobody wants to "poach" a student from another group, or something in between. If the latter case is more important, then an intervention by the person in charge is all that is needed. If the impression you give us is correct, (and someone else might have a very different view, this happens without malice on either side), then the system is failing you, but only because you do not turn to it. No academic institution likes to have students who "age out" of graduation.
The final outcome might be (a) giving up, because you are judged to be a bad prospect by several independent people, (b) moving to a different institution, which will be much easier if you have help from your current institution, (c) join another group, which again is easier if there is a push from above, or (d) graduating in your current group after misunderstandings etc. have been cleared up and responsibilities reassigned.
We do not know you, but we know mostly how academia in general functions. Dysfunctional departments and institutions are rare and usually are quite obvious to people on the inside, so I at least trust that your institution is benevolent to you in principle.

My specific experience is in high energy theory at universities in the US, though I'm more broadly familiar with other areas of theoretical physics as well. I'm going to be honest, and I'm sorry that my assessment will be less rosy than some other responses.
Usually it is not possible to graduate without publications; one sees this only very rarely. When universities have a specific requirement, often it is 3 publications. Not always though. You should figure out the situation at your university as soon as you can.
I am sorry that your adviser has not been responsible and has let you down. This is not fair to you, and it is not an ethical way for them to act. Spending three years after being done with classes but feeling like you 'don't have an actual working research project' is frankly a lot of time to have wasted.
It is possible to write papers as a graduate student without any people with PhDs. I had a couple, but this was after I had written a few papers with my advisor, and I don't think I could have done it without this earlier experience.
If you have talked to your adviser and they are unwilling to step up, then you must put maximum effort into finding someone else who can mentor you. If other professors are not an option, you should try to have some frank conversations with postdocs and ask if you can assist them on some of their projects (or if you have good enough ideas, if they can work with you on them and guide you). If it doesn't work with postdocs, then you should ask other graduate students if you can collaborate with them.
Unfortunately, spinning your wheels with no guidance is not likely to get you anywhere. I hope you can find someone who is willing to collaborate. In your position I think you should be happy to do the lion's share of calculations on some project in exchange for a senior collaborator's guidance.

First, publication expectations differ greatly based on discipline. With STEM, my understanding based on talking with various academics and current PhD students is that there is an expectation to publish. Across the four years of a PhD, I understand that, at least in my country, students will publish around two to three papers. Of course this should be taken with a pinch of salt.
The key issue is that post-doctoral positions are highly competitive. PhD positions are competitive and realistically only a number will be able to gain postdoctoral positions. During applications and interviews for these, the interviewer will very much ask questions concerning yours research at PhD level, and will likely ask if you have any papers, or at least a research project.
The good news is that this is fixable, and you should not put pressure on yourself or feel that you are falling behind. Clearly you have the knowledge necessary - you passed what I imagine were difficult qualification exams, and the fact that your university admitted you to the program is evidence that they have faith in your abilities.
Your supervisor should be guiding you to do this, focusing your research interests to a specific project idea. They should help you learn the ins and outs of research, and provide technical advice. If this has failed, all I can suggest is that you consider asking around the department as much as possible. Email professors, search the website for the various staff’s research interest and see which align with yours, and mention this in the email. Explain your position and your desire to do research and to focus on a specific project. Whilst they may not be able to replace your supervisor, various professors may be conducting research which they need assistance with, and if you can help collaborate with this, it’s great experience for you. Even if this is not an option, asking professors who have similar interests for advice can be greatly useful because they may be able to help you pick a research topic which aligns with your interests.
Also make sure you talk with other PhD students.
